# Missing rows when converting select to subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am flabbergasted by these results. When wrapping a query in a sub-query the group by clause suddenly drops all rows with a certain value.

Could anyone help me figure out what this might happen?

Here is my problem in a nutshell, I do not understand last result:

```
with my_cte as (
 select complex stuff from tables
)

select checktype from my_cte group by checktype
```

This returns 2 rows: PRE,POST.

```
with my_cte as (
 select complex stuff from tables
)

select distinct checktype from my_cte
```

This also returns 2 rows: PRE,POST.

```
with my_cte as (
 select complex stuff from tables
)

select * from (
  select distinct checktype from my_cte
)
```

This also returns 2 rows: PRE,POST

```
with my_cte as (
 select complex stuff from tables
)

select * from (
  select checktype from my_cte group by checktype
)
```

This only returns 1 rows! PRE. Why?

The same thing happens if I use another CTE instead of a sub-query.

Why would a subquery in oracle suddenly drop all rows of a certain value?

Oracle version:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: can you add sample data with table structure  here.

Comment: I made a quick test : `with my_cte as (                                
 select 'PRE' AS checktype from dual            
 UNION ALL                                      
 select 'POST' AS checktype from dual           
)                                               
                                                
select * from (
  select checktype from my_cte group by checktype
)` on Oracle 11g, and I can NOT reproduce your issue, results are correct

Comment: Trow my query and provide results

Comment: Post a reproducible test case or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around I found that in my CTEs I use a TABLE function together with a UNION ALL, this seems to be the cause of the trouble:

```
WITX X AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT
       T.TS,
       TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TREPSUMMARY, '.+', 1, LEVELS.COLUMN_VALUE)) AS MISSING,
       DATE
     FROM 
       BASE_POST_EXCEPTIONS T,
       TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT    BY  LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(   T.CMPLEXTREPSUMMARY, '.+'))  + 1) AS ODCINUMBERLIST)) LEVELS
     WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.CMPLEXTREPSUMMARY, '.+', 1,    LEVELS.COLUMN_VALUE) LIKE 'my query'
)

Y AS (
  SELECT TS, MISSING, DATE FROM G
),

MY_UNION AS (
  SELECT * FROM X /* CAUSED TROUBLE SOMEHOW */
  UNOIN ALL
  SELECT * FROM Y
)
```

In order to get around the bug I had to hint to the query planner to materilize the tables before the UNION ALL

```
MY_UNION AS (
  SELECT /*+ materialize */ * FROM X
  UNOIN ALL
  SELECT /*+ materialize */ * FROM Y
)
```

No idea why this happens. Will try to reverse engineer and create a simple reproducible test case.